# debug.log for XposedBridge?

Tags: android

I currently work on an application with XposedBridge and I have a lot of questions. I will start with the simple ones.

1. How can I get the debug.log file?

   I cannot find the debug.log file. I have tried the phone shell as well as two adb ways : 
   A. adb shell data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/log/debug.log
   B. adb shell "su -c 'cat data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/log/debug.log'"
   C. adb shell cat data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/log/debug.log

   adb says : " No such file or directory "

   The phone shell can cd to /data and /data/data but not after. Cannot ls neither of the data's. Says access denied. So does adb when I try adb ls.

   The phone, Moto E XT1023, is rooted. Despite, shell cannot read some directories. I have posted a question why here but no one seems to care to answer.

   I had to go to ES File Explorer. Managed to get to /data. ES says folder empty. Managed to get to Emulator/0/de.robv.android.xposed.installer or something alike. There was a subdirectory called files. Inside was the installer. No debug.log.

   Searched all directories with ES for debug.log. Nothing found.
2. Once I create the XposedBridge class in a separate file of the project and once I do whatever XposedBridge is supposed to do (override methods, insert code before and or after the methods, etcetera) the overridden methods or the methods with code run before and or after or the overridden data will continue to be overridden until the app exits. Is this true?
3. Is there any simple, yet powerful and comprehensive manual or reference or, the best, a tutorial?
4. Can I specify another directory for the debug.log.file?
5. In case I am able to make a directory \data\data manually, would this make the Xposed save debug.log there?

I am so happy I have managed to partially answer the first question which is not only related to XposedBridge but is a global root reach question for rooted phones, so I cannot even think of any other questions for now. I do not have a debug.log but I have error.log and I know how to read these. Here is how in case anyone is interested :

In order to be able to reed XposedBridge log files :

1. Go to the specialised Moto E adb ( may work with a standard one too ).
2. Type :

   ```
   ************ 
   * adb root * 
   ************
   ```

   to ensure root access.
3. The Dollar Sign $ must appear as the sign before commands. $ means the adb shell environment has been entered.
4. After $, type :

   ```
   ****** 
   * su * 
   ******
   ```
5. The Sharp Sign # must appear as the sign before commands. # means root has been entered. Once root has been entered, there is a full access to the phone. Thus :

   ```
   ************************************************** 
   * cd /data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer * 
   **************************************************
   ```

   can be executed and the directory /data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer will be entered.
6. Type :

   ```
   ****** 
   * ls * 
   ******
   ```

   to see the contents of this directory.
7. In case error.log or debug.log files are there, type :

   ```
   ***************** 
   * cat error.log * 
   *****************
   ```

   and or

   ```
   ***************** 
   * cat debug.log * 
   *****************
   ```

   to view these files.
8. Type :

   ```
   ******** 
   * exit * 
   ********
   ```

   to return to the safer $ prompt.
9. Type :

   ```
   ******** 
   * exit * 
   ********
   ```

   to exit adb.

   Note : adb root may not run while a project is developed. The rest works, though.

I still do not have any debug.log. May be the XposedBridge lines do not run. Will check with some simple method from the manual.

Here is what I have found out, though. I have created an empty text file called debug.log on the computer and transferred the file to the main root of the device, the /sdcard directory, themn copied the file to /data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/log just to see what happens. Nothing happens. The file is empty.

Here is what I have found out which may be helpful:

---

COMMANDS TO READ THE LOG FILES :

```
adb shell 
su 
cd /data/data/de.robv.android.xposed.installer/log 
cat error.log
```

USE cp SOURCE DESTINATION after su shell, the # prompt, to copy files from one

directory to another on the device.

---

IMPORTANT NOTES :

---

All Xposed classes must be put in xposed_init, otherwise Android Studio 1.2 reports them as never used.

---

In built.gradle, have :

```
/* SSB : Added manually so the gradle builds with the 
XposedBridgeApi-54.jar which is in the app -> libs 
but not to include the jar in the apk. */
dependencies {
provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

THESE HAVE BEEN PUT MANUALLY.

---

Update : I have been able to clean the code and have managed to find why I do not have a debug.log. This is because the two XposedBridge classes I have ( one is initialisation of zygote and the other is the work file with hooks and replacements ) are not loaded. The error.log shows : Didn't find class " package ( strts without a com. ) NameOfThePackageWithoutComDot.NameOfTheExposedClass in the NameOfThePackageWithoutComDot-2.apk "

THIS IS SAID FOR THE TWO CLASSES.

Comment: Have you tried to login as su to get a superuser shell? (i.e. just do `su`)?

Comment: Yes. This was not the problem. I solved the problem partially. See the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem partially solved:

I have removed the string " package " from the xposed_init and this solved the problem. Thus, instead of :

```
package TheNameOfThePackage.TheNameOfTheClass
```

xposed_init contains :

```
TheNameOfThePackage.TheNameOfTheClass
```

without the word " package " in front of the names as Android Studio usually puts and requires.

Now, the custom class seems to load OK and XMain where zygote is init generates a novel.

Regardless, the custom class with the test code works OK. The debug.log file is generated. However, the application does not seem to write in the file and the debug.log only says :

```
d.xposed.installer/log/debug.log
```

inside.